# Use of the color package changes the height of the text block

Tags: spacing, color, margins, paper-size

Here is the packages in my documents:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\setlength{\textheight}{23.4 cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}
\pagestyle{myheadings}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\date{}
```

[image: My document in pdf]

My problem is when I'm using color package and apply it to one of the words of my doc, 
the document doesn't have a bottom space. Note that if I don't use the color
package and standard black and white word, then we have a normal bottom space and everything is fine.

[image: Normal document not using color]

Thanks for your help.

Here is my entire code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\hyphenation{o-pe-ra-tors}
\hyphenation{ge-ne-ra-li-za-ti-on}
\hyphenation{ge-ne-ra-li-zed}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\setcounter{page}{1}

\setlength{\textheight}{23.4 cm}

\setlength{\textwidth}{14cm}

\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1cm}

\setlength{\evensidemargin}{1cm}

\pagestyle{myheadings}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\markboth{\small{wasjcbjab cja}}
{\small{saknckjndsckjndsk}}

\date{}
\begin{document}


\centerline {\Large{\bf TES}}

\centerline{}

\centerline{\Large{\bf TES}}

\centerline{}
\centerline{\Large{\bf TESSS}}

\centerline{}

\centerline{}

\centerline{\bf { TESSS}}

\centerline{Department ofTESSS}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{}

\centerline{\bf {TESSS}}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{TESSS.}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{}

\centerline{\bf {TESSS}}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{TESSS}


\centerline{}
\centerline{\bf {TESSS }}

\centerline{TESSS,}

\centerline{TESSS}

\centerline{TESSSTESSS}

\newtheorem{Theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\newtheorem{Definition}[Theorem]{Definition}

\newtheorem{Corollary}[Theorem]{Corollary}

\newtheorem{Lemma}[Theorem]{Lemma}

\newtheorem{remark}[Theorem]{Remark}

\newtheorem{Example}[Theorem]{Example}
\newtheorem{proposition}[Theorem]{Proposition}
\newenvironment{proof}[1][Proof]{\noindent\textbf{#1.} }{\ \rule{0.5em}{0.5em}}

\begin{abstract}
\noindent  
TESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSST


ESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTES

SSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSSTES
SSTESSSTESSSTESSSTESSS

ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem

ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem

ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProbl
emProblemProblemProblemProblemProble
mProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem

ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem


ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem

ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem



ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemP

roblemProblemProblemProblemProblemPr



oblemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro


blemProblemProblemProblemProblemProbl

emProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProble
mProblemProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProbl
emProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemP

roblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProble
mProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProb
lemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemPr
oblemProblemProblemProblemProb
lemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProblemProble
mProblemProblemProblemProblem
ProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blemProblemProblemProblemProble
mProblemProblemProblemProblemPr
oblemProblemProblemProblemProble

mProblemProblemProblemProblemProb
lemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blemProblemProblemProblemProblemPro
blem
\end{abstract}

{\bf ication:} adjhabsdjabfcjbacj. \\

{\bf Keywords:} TESSSSS.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that adding 4 spaces to the code that you post in your question will treat it as code, rather than text.  Alternately, you can highlight the code, and press the `{}` button above the edit box, which will indent the highlighted material automatically.

Comment: Please make a small complete example that shows the problem. Presumably one of your definitions does not correctly work with latex colour support but it's hard to say what's wrong unless you show the code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: I have added my entire code above

Comment: I was able to recreate your problem.  It appeared that the actual paper size was changing with the two different versions.  What I did was to add `\usepackage[portrait]{geometry}` and that at least made a consistent rendering with and without the `color` package.  As to why, I'm not sure.  By the way, the `xcolor` package is preferred to the `color` package.

Answer (score 3):

For historical reasons LaTeX settings such as `[a4paper]` or `\textwidth` set the dimensions of the printing text area but not of the physical media size.

The graphics package driver (in common with other oackages such as `hyperref` and `geometry` does set the physical media size using driver or engine specific code. For pdftex this means that `\pdfpageheight` gets set. This causes the specified page size (and so the position of the text in the pdf viewer to be set to match the specified text area rather than left at its default (which is probably USLetter or A4).

If you add

```
\showthe\pdfpageheight
```

you will find that it is `845.04684pt` or `794.96999pt` depending on whether the `color` package is used.

You can set this value (and `\pdfpagewidth`) directly with `\setlength` after loading `color` then the values will not change if you comment out the color package.

---

some other issues that turn out to be unrelated here but should probably be fixed anyway.

`\centerline` isn't really a latex command, use the `center` environment

`\bf` is deprecated (it is just for latex2.09 compatibility) use `\textbf{aaa}` or `{\bfseries aaa}`

Size changing commands do not take an argument and should include a paragraph en (otherwise the line spacing will be incorrect) so `{\large aaaa\par}` not `\large{aaaa}`

Don't end a paragraph with `\\` or you get the warning:

```
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 167--168
```